# How to transform values from a Hash Table to a different columns?

Tags: string, excel, powershell, hash, hashtable

I'm new in Power Shell so I'm having  a hard time to understand which command to use to a certain operation.

**PROBLEM:** I have a hash table where every parameter can have 4 different words in a string that composes the field VALUE. Eg.:

```
$table:

Name                    Value
-----                   --------
parameter 1             F15 STK15                                                                                                                                                             
parameter 2             STK15
parameter 3             GP F15 STK15
```

As you can see, the table has 3 parameters and each parameter value is a STRING that could be formed by 3 different words: STK F15 and GP.

What I really need is to EXPORT this hash table to EXCEL in 4 different columns:

```
NAME    GP   STK15    F15
```

So in EXCEL there will be 4 columns:

```
NAME          GP    STK15    F15
parameter1    NULL  STK15    F15
and so on.
```

I don't know how to do it, piping with | out-GridView or what ever.

If I could divide the string into 3 columns it already would be perfect. can someone help me ?

Comment: `$table.'parameter 1'` give you access to its value, so it will return the string `"F15 STK15"`

Comment: Did you already try something?

Comment: I know, how to get to the value. I need to SPLIT the value into 3 columns
Lets say I have 

parameter 1.value = "AAA BBB CCC"

I need to split "AAA BBB CCC" into 3 different columns and send it to EXCEL (in 3 different columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```powershell
$table = @{parameter1="F15 STK15";parameter2="STK15";parameter3="GP F15 STK15"}
$outArray = @()

foreach($entry in $table.GetEnumerator()) {
   $o = new-object PSCustomObject
   $o | Add-Member -notepropertyName "NAME" -notepropertyvalue $entry.name
   "F15","STK15","GP" | % { 
      if($entry.Value -match $_) {
        $o | Add-Member -notepropertyname "$_" -notepropertyvalue "$_"
      }
      else {
        $o | Add-Member -notepropertyname "$_" -notepropertyvalue "NULL"
      }
    }  
    $outArray += ,$o
}
```

Iterate over the table and check for a match of each of the data you're trying to identify. Create a custom object for each value in the hashtable and populate it with the name, the required data and whether or not the each of the data were matched. Then append the object to an array.

You then have an object as such:

```powershell
[PS] > $outArray | ft -auto

NAME       F15  STK15 GP
----       ---  ----- --
parameter2 NULL STK15 NULL
parameter1 F15  STK15 NULL
parameter3 F15  STK15 GP
```

And you can convert it to a `csv` format for exporting to Excel;

```powershell
[PS] > $outArray | sort -Property NAME | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"NAME","F15","STK15","GP"
"parameter1","F15","STK15","NULL"
"parameter2","NULL","STK15","NULL"
"parameter3","F15","STK15","GP"
```

Comment: One last thing, how can I send it to excel in 4 columns ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Format is currently in 4 columns. Pipe it to `| Out-File` cmdlet to save it to disk then open the csv in Excel

Comment: piping it to |out-file creates a file that has only one column with:
"parameter1","F15","STK15","NULL" 
in the first cell.

Couldn't find out how to split it into 4 columns so far.

Comment: You need to open it as a csv file - choosing `,` as the delimiter. If you save it as `whatever.csv` Excel should do this automatically

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works just the way I wanted to, but still when I pipe the final array to out file...

$outArray | sort -Property NAME | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | out-file "$pwd\test.csv" 

all I get is one column with all the members. I tried also with -delemiter "," but it does not work.

Can you give me a hand ?